# Подсчет площади трапеции из элементов массива

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется многомерный массив:

```
$arr = array( 
  array( 'a' => 11, 'b' => 14, 'c' => 19), 
  array( 'a' => 15, 'b' => 18, 'c' => 21), 
  array( 'a' => 14, 'b' => 12, 'c' => 23) 
);
```

Как вывести три площади трапеции по формуле `$s = 1/2 * $c *($a + $b);` ? И требуется занести эти значения в новый массив?

Comment: странный вопрос, так как у вас есть и данные и формула :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать функцию `extract`:

```
foreach ($array as $item) { 
    extract($item);
    $stack [] = 1/2 * $c * ($a + $b); 
}

print_r($stack);
```

Answer (score 1):

Подобное отображение проще всего сделать с помощью [array_map](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php):

```
$res = array_map(function($item) {
  return $item['c']*($item['a']+$item['b']) / 2;
}, $arr);
```

Ну или можно пройтись циклом(приведу интересный пример с деструктурированием):

```
$res = [];
foreach ($arr as ['a' => $a, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c]) {
    $res[] = $c*($a+$b) / 2;
}
```

Comment: интересный вариант :)